# Connect to a database using Zend Registry

Tags: php, zend-framework

I'm new to the Zend framework. I'm trying to connect a database using Zend Registry, but I'm not able to.

Here is my bootstrap class.

```
<?php
class Bootstrap extends Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Bootstrap {
     public function _initDb(){
         $db = new Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql(
            array(
                'host' => 'localhost',
                'username' => 'ragn',
                'password' => 'app',
                'dbname' => 'apple'
            )
        );
        Zend_Db_Table_Abstract::setDefaultAdapter($db);
        Zend_Registry::set('db', $db);
    }
}
?>
```

And here is my `IndexController` class.

```
class IndexController extends Zend_Controller_Action {


    public function init()
    {
        /* Initialize action controller here */
    }

    public function indexAction()
    {


        $db = Zend_Registry::get('dbadapter');
        $select = new Zend_Db_Select($db);
        $select = $db->select();
        $select = $db->select() -> from(
            array('client' => 'client'),
            array ('idclient')) -> join(array('apartmentclient' => 'apartmentclient'),
            'client.idclient = apartmentclient.idclient',
            array ('idapartment')) -> join(array('description' => 'description'),
            'apartmentclient.idapartment = description.idapartment',array ('title'));
        $stmt = $select->query();
        $result = $stmt->fetchAll();
        $Settext = array();
        $SetName = array();
        $SetName = "$result[2]";
        $Settext = "Hi!Can you please provide feedback for the apartment";
        $this->view->Settext = $Settext." ".$SetName;    

    }
}
```

I have the details application.ini file also.

```
resources.db.adapter = PDO_MYSQL
resources.db.isDefaultAdapter = true
resources.db.params.host = localhost
resources.db.params.username = ragn
resources.db.params.password = app
resources.db.params.dbname = apple
```

Could anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: What do you mean by "not able to"?  Is the database restricting access?  Do you have proper permissions to connect to the database?  Does that database exist with that *exact* user and login credentials?  Could you fill in the blanks here?

Comment: Hi.Thanks for the reply.I'm just trying to querying it out.It says Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded.Yes am trying with the correct login credentials.I don know do I need have a entry in some other file like .htaccess?.....

Comment: You really only need to set up your database adapter in the application.ini or the bootstrap.php. You're setting the same adapter twice.`$db=new Zend_Config($this->getOption('db');` in your bootstrap will get the adapter from application.ini

Answer (score 3):

In your code there're errors. You set the database in the registry using the key 'db':

```
Zend_Registry::set('db', $db);
```

but you try to retrieve it using the key 'dbadapter':

```
$db = Zend_Registry::get('dbadapter');
```

It should be like this:

```
$db = Zend_Registry::get('db');
```

Moreover this line is useless:

```
$select = $db->select();
```

This line:

```
$SetName = "$result[2]";
```

can be like this:

```
$SetName = $result[2];
```

Since you write this line:

```
$result = $stmt->fetchAll();
```

you have to retrieve the values in a loop.

To spot the error you have to use a debugger but if you don't know how to use it, a simple while worst method is to use the function `die();`. Move this function along your code and when you find that the script doesn't stop and came back with the error you wrote, you found the problematic line.

Comment: Hi,Many many thanks for your reply.Now I have removed my code in application.ini and changed $db = Zend_Registry::get('db'); also in the indexcontroller.But still am receiving error like Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in C:\xampp\htdocs\Firstzen\library\Zend\Db\Statement\Pdo.php on line 221.As I am new to PHP I'm really not able to find out what it is.Could you pls tell me what is wrong???

Answer (score 1):

First you can remove method _initDb() form your bootstrap . Since ZF does this for you by reading your application.ini

Second you don't need to store your db  in registry since purpose of storing in registry is to access something from wherever you like which can be accomplish simply by

```
$db = Zend_Db_Table::getDefaultAdapter();
```